# Resizing an image using Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I tried using `version :thumb` in the class that was provided by the carrierwave. However when I used the `version :thumb` class, the image has an error, it add `thumb` in the url, breaking the image.

```
<img src="/uploads/course/image/2/thumb_OX50XkO.jpg" alt="Thumb ox50xko">
```

Original image link doesn't have the word `thumb` in the url.

**EDIT:**

Model:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :course_categories
    has_many :categories, :through => :course_categories
    has_many :course_locations
    has_many :locations, :through => :course_locations
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Uploader:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
    storage :file
    def store_dir
        "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end

    version :thumb do
        process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
    end
end
```

Comment: share your model where you are uploading/processing versions

Answer (score 0):

To output image you can try to use `image_tag @course.image.url(:thumb)` or `uploader.thumb.url`. If you added thumb after image was uploaded, you need to upload it again or test it for another @course object.

It's okay, that name of file is differ, since it's already another file - you have your original file and cropped.

Comment: I used both of them, and it doesn't resize

Comment: what do you mean "and it doesn't resize"? is it show original dimensions? Please, try to restart your rails server and upload new image for a new course instance.

Comment: @railsh did you try it?